# When did system-on-chip (SoC) arrive in mainstream laptops? Are intel chipsets used in laptops such as XPS 13, SoCs?

Tags: soc, intel

An SoC has multiple functional units like CPU, GPU, sometimes DSPs(Digital Signal Processors), memory and many other units embedded in a single chip. Most intel chipsets used in laptops do have integrated graphics, so in that sense, are they SoCs? Wikipedia mentions SoCs arriving to mainstream laptops as of 2018, but intel chipsets had integrated graphics even before 2018. Is Wikipedia correct? The question is open to other laptop chipsets such as AMD too.

Comment: To those considering downvoting and closing the question, stop first to consider that there is an element of interest to this question, which revolves around how SoC devices are defined. It is definitely possible to answer the question with citations rather than straight oppinion, so closing as opinion based seems a little premature. Perhaps the question could be slightly reformulated to make that clearer.

Comment: SOC is a bad term to use here, but in terms of intel/x86, according to wikipedia Nahalem is when the northbridge and southbridge were integrated, essentially make it much closer to an SOC.  This became westmere, sandy bridge and the die shrink to ivy bridge, one/some of these were in laptops...Implied/stated basically in these articles is that this is when the i3/i5/i7 nomenclatures started and those were in laptops from essentially the beginning.  So I think that was well before 2018.  if you consider SOC also including graphics, etc, then that may be in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't SoCs, the RAM is external.

The point of SoCs is that all the standard components are in a single IC, so only low-speed interfaces for the application are on the outside, which simplifies the design of the PCB a lot.

SoCs with display outputs are seldom as well, as these too are high-speed signals that are difficult to route on a PCB, it's more common to combine them with a display with integrated controller, typically via SPI. These will be small and have slow updates, so they are unsuitable for laptops.

Comment: RAM is the wrong standard, plenty of actual SoC's don't include it as it's not actually practical to do so except via package on package which only took off after the SoC idea and is still far from universal.  It's more the support chips that disqualify a typical laptop...

Comment: Yes, the standard I use is more "no complex interfaces required to get code running on it", where "complex" is either "lots of pins" or "has impedance requirements". Still wobbly as a definition, but "SoC" is more of a marketing term that says "we took care of all the complexity for you".

Answer (score 0):

A System-On-Chip (SoC) is a very loosely defined term, but essentially can be considered as a solution which provides all of the necessary functionality for a given system integrated into a single IC. This is usually a single die, but can also include vertical integration such as Package-On-Package and horizontal integration in the form of System-On-Package.

The key defining feature is that the chip can basically run standalone once power is supplied. Features like power regulation and clocking are usually considered seperately, as are external storage such as flash memory and external RAM which are useful for expansion.

There are many types of SoC:

- Simple microcontrollers with processor, flash, RAM, IO can be considered SoCs.
- More modern SoCs include larger processor + RAM + IO combos
- Some then also include a GPU for graphics
- Some which include an FPGA for co-processing
- Some are more related to mixed signal analogue + digital + processor

There is no hard and fast requirement for a SoC to have a large external RAM integration. It might of course have an external memory controller integrated. The lack of say DDR memory does not disqualify a device from being considered a SoC. For example the Cyclone V SoC devices are FPGA + Processor + 64kB executable on-chip RAM.

---

With regard to the "SoCs are being applied to mainstream personal computers as of 2018" claim from Wikipedia, that links to a blog post which talks about arm entering the consumer PC market with a roadmap through 2020. It doesn't in any way discuss system-on-chip. There isn't anything else given there that specifically backs up the statement, and so should be taken with a pinch of salt. I presume that whomever wrote the Wiki article is simply assuming that if its an arm processor, it must be a SoC when adding that reference.

Doing a bit more research, the Surface Go released in 2018 makes use of an Intel Pentium Gold 4415Y processor. There are a number of sites, usually marketing sites and blogs, that refer to this as a SoC device. However Intel don't refer to this processor as a SoC on their [specification page](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122697/intel-pentium-gold-processor-4415y-2m-cache-1-60-ghz.html).

Having said that, as a [Kaby Lake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/kaby_lake) processor, the 4415Y starts to come under the class of **System on Package** type devices, whereby multiple dies are placed within the same physical package (or in this case interposer board). The [4415Y is indeed](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/pentium_gold/4415y) a two die device.

Indeed further looking around Kaby Lake processors reveals the Kaby Lake-G series which **do in fact include DDR RAM** - they use the Hybrid Memory Cube technology to integrate several DDR memory chips on the same physical package as the processor, which would in fact put it into the book of something which could operate standalone. The HP Spectre x360 and Dell XPS 15, models of both released in 2018 make use this SoP processor. So yes, mainstream laptops in 2018 **did** include SoC type processors.